# Meta Marketing API - Ad Creative Preview Error For Dynamic Catalog

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**Issue**

I'm using the meta marketing API to preview ad creatives in a client dashboard. Recently, when previewing an ad for a dynamic automotive catalog, the below error message appears. Anybody seeing this and have an idea of what to do?

**Error Message**

- No valid products in the product set: All the products in the selected product set are filtered out. Products must be loadable or visible to viewer. Products must be active or published. Products should not be expired. Products cannot be out of stock.

[image]

**Additional Details**

When previewing an ad with a static image or carousel ad with no catalog, there are no issues.

The catalog itself doesn't show any error messages and is serving with impressions, generating clicks, etc.

I'm using the Facebook Business PHP SDK. I've also tried the Facebook Business Python SDK locally and got the same error message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue with the Facebook platform. An ETA for a fix was not provided but here is a link to the open bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/6823759634341447/